# Can't make the Apidemo mediaplayer work newbie

Tags: android, media-player

I have created a projects called rtva to use the media player.
I have taken all files from the APIdemos/media 
MediaPlayerDemo_Audio.java (renamed to rtva_Audio.java)
MediaPlayerDemo_Video.java (renamed to rtva_Video.java)
MediaPlayerDemo_Video.java (renamed to rtva.java)
Corresponding layouts have also been copied.

When i Launch the application in my virtual device or samsung galaxy s phone  i got a crash (see log below).
The problem is that i get the first layout and whatever button i press after that the application crashes. I'm using android 2.2 under linux with eclipse

It seems that for example if i press the localaudio button (note that i havn't added any path at this stage so i should at least get the message that i should set the  path as stated in the rtva_video.java file. Well it crashes after pressing the button.

The debugger pinponts to  the startactivity(intent) line below:

```
private OnClickListener mLocalAudioListener = new OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent =
                    new Intent(rtva.this.getApplication(),
                            rtva_Audio.class);
                    intent.putExtra(MEDIA, LOCAL_AUDIO);
                    startActivity(intent); <---- debugger highlights this line

        }
```

Here is the log file:

```
starting activity com.rtva.player.rtva on device emulator-5554
[2010-11-02 14:30:28 - rtva] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.rtva.player/.rtva }
[2010-11-02 14:30:29 - rtva] Attempting to connect debugger to 'com.rtva.player' on port 8634
```

Debug info:

```
// Compiled from Instrumentation.java (version 1.5 : 49.0, super bit)
public class android.app.Instrumentation {

  // Field descriptor #13 Ljava/lang/String;
  public static final java.lang.String REPORT_KEY_IDENTIFIER = "id";

  // Field descriptor #13 Ljava/lang/String;
  public static final java.lang.String REPORT_KEY_STREAMRESULT = "stream";

  // Method descriptor #19 ()V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 1
  public Instrumentation();
     0  aload_0 [this]
     1  invokespecial java.lang.Object() [1]
     4  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
     7  dup
     8  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
    10  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
    13  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 22]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 14] local: this index: 0 type: android.app.Instrumentation

  // Method descriptor #26 (Landroid/os/Bundle;)V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 2
  public void onCreate(android.os.Bundle arguments);
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
     3  dup
     4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 23]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: android.app.Instrumentation
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: arguments index: 1 type: android.os.Bundle

  // Method descriptor #19 ()V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 1
  public void start();
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
     3  dup
     4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 24]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: android.app.Instrumentation

  // Method descriptor #19 ()V
  // Stack: 3, Locals: 1
  public void onStart();
     0  new java.lang.RuntimeException [2]
     3  dup
     4  ldc <String "Stub!"> [3]
     6  invokespecial java.lang.RuntimeException(java.lang.String) [4]
     9  athrow
      Line numbers:
        [pc: 0, line: 25]
      Local variable table:
        [pc: 0, pc: 10] local: this index: 0 type: android.app.Instrumentation
  .....
.......
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have not copied over some critical piece such as a resource, or have not renamed it to match your new naming scheme.

You have not included any actual errors in your 'log file'

Comment: I'm really newbie but  what do you mean by ressource ??Can you be more specific ?

Comment: Ok i understand. But which resources are missing ?? layout have been copied and they are the only ones that i need so far, that's my guess.